# Проверка совпадения данных в массиве

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$array = array(
'id' => 'key1', 'key2', 'key3'
);
```

Как сделать, чтобы можно было проверить на совпадение данных в массиве?
Типа следующего:

```
if($array['id']==$key){
   совпаденгие есть...
}
```

Но сейчас совпадение есть лишь в случае, когда $key==key1, то есть первому значению 'id'. Пробовал сделать типа

```
$array = array(
'id' => 'key1' or 'key2' or 'key3'
);
```

Но это не помогло, да и вряд ли это можно сделать.

Comment: смутный вопрос) можно покорректней - непонятно что с чем вам нада сравнить(

Answer (score 1):

обычно так делают:

```
$ids = array(
  'key1',
  'key2',
  'key3',
);
if (in_array('key2', $ids)) {
  // 'key2' in $ids
}
```

Вообще, запись (ваша)

```
$array = array( 'id' => 'key1', 'key2', 'key3' );
```

на самом деле создает массив `( 'id' => 'key1', 0 => 'key2', 1 => 'key3')`, потому у меня есть подозрение, что вы не совсем понимаете, что пишете)

Есть веротность, что хотелось так:

```
$array = array(
  'id' => array(
    'key1',
    'key2',
    'key3',
  )
);
if (in_array($key, $array['id'])) {
  // $key in $array['id']
}
```

В общем, выбирайте)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $a){
    if($a==$key){
        Совпадение есть...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть две( насколько мне известно ) функции:

**Возвращает ключ** к совпавшему значению массива:

```
mixed array_search ( mixed needle, array haystack [, bool strict] )
```

**Возвращает true/false :**

```
bool in_array ( mixed needle, array haystack [, bool strict] )
```

1